# Does Qt have a way to get the font that the particular css resolves to?

Tags: css, qt, fonts

CSS stylesheets are used for the Qt window. One of QLabels has text with more stylesheets in it.

As I understand it, these stylesheets are applied on top of each other.

Does Qt have a way to determine what font is ultimately used? In other words, given a particular QLabel and a particulat stylesheet in its text (ex. 'font-family:monospace;'), is there a way to determine what font is used for this text?